# Fade video in a MediaElement in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

In my WPF application, I have a slider that controls the opacity of a video. I would also like to be able to click a button and the video gradually fades up over a set period (maybe 1 second?).

I know how to control a video's opacity, but the bit I'm struggling with is the fade. I imagine I would need some sort of thing where it increases the opacity slightly, then waits a tiny amount of time then increases it again, until opacity equals one? But I'm not sure how to implement this, code-wise?

Could you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [animate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) the MediaElement's Opacity property:

```
mediaElement.BeginAnimation(
    UIElement.OpacityProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation(0d, 1d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d)));
```